# Serialize nested objects with XStream

Tags: object, nested, serialization, xstream

I have an object A which contains an object B. B has some fields. Is is possible, when serializing A to XML with XStream, to have all fields of B appear at the same level as fields of A?

More concretely, I have the following classes:

```
class B{ 
String foo = "bar";
}

class A{
B b;
}
```

I would like the output to look like:

```
<A>
  <foo>bar</foo>
</A>
```

Instead of

```
<A>
<B>
<foo>bar</foo>
</B>
</A>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [xstream flatten an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216943/xstream-flatten-an-object)